# Remove non-existent Windows loader from GRUB

Tags: 12.04, grub2

When I run `update-grub` on Ubuntu 12.04 on my system, I get the following output:

```
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-29-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-29-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1
```

What bugs me is the Windows 7 loader. `/dev/sda` indeed had Windows 7 on it previously. However, my goal was to complete erase that. During install, I deleted the partition table and created two partitions on each drive for RAID 1. So now I got:

```
md1 : active raid1 sdb2[1] sda2[0]
      1855727424 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md0 : active raid1 sdb1[1] sda1[0]
      97589120 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
```

`md0` = `/` and `md1` = `/home`, both formatted with `ext4`.

Why GRUB keeps insisting that there is a Windows 7 loader is beyond me. Where is this loader located and how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Windows 7 boot process uses not only MBR, but also VBR (volume boot record), which is contained on the first 512 bytes of the partition.

So I would try to zero all sda1, e.g.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda1 bs=1M
```

And run `update-grub` again.

Comment: I have my Ubuntu installed on that partition, so I can't just erase it. However, superblock 1.2 starts 4096 bytes from the beginning of sda1, right? Are the bytes before that completely unused? Is it save to zero out only the first 512 bytes?

Comment: Well, you could always check for VBR by looking and first 512 bytes of the partition `hexdump -C -n 512 /dev/sda1` - there should be `55 aa` signature. And yes, superblock starts at 4K, so it should be safe to zero. But make a backup first!

Comment: `dd` is —for good reasons— also known as disk destroy. Caution with this!

Answer (score 0):

### 1 just stop (windows) OS probing

```
sudo chmod a-x /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober
```

...and you should see, that no more windows probing is happening on your next `sudo update-grub`. (`a+x` to revert). More 'tricky' but less 'invasive'.

### ...or 2 (wipe MBR)

1. create backup
2. verify, there truly is an MBR (ends on `55 aa`, as said by maniaque)
3. wipe the mbr. Be extra careful, also about sda**x** number,  [have read this before](http://www.linuxjournal.com/magazine/hack-and-when-disaster-strikes-restoring-master-boot-record?page=0,0).

code:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda1 of=~/mbr_sda1_backup bs=512 count=1
hexdump -C -n 512 /dev/sda1
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda1 bs=512 count=1
```